# PHP add to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
$myarray = array(
          'data'=>
             array('age'=>10)
           );
```

How to more data to **$myarray['data']**

```
$newdata = array('gender'=>'male');
```

so that I end up with

```
$myarray = array(
          'data'=>
             array(
                'age'=>10
                'gender'=>'male'
                 )
           );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this;

```
$myarray['data']['gender'] = "male";
```

Here is a working demo : **[Demo](http://ideone.com/fSFpQm)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$myarray['data']['something'] = "Whatever";`

Hope this helps.